# Comparacion entre dos input javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito comparar dos inputs al presionar la tecla enter, en los que primero introduzco un número de referencia, y en el segundo siempre voy a introducir el mismo numero relacionado con esa referencia, puede ser de 1 a 3000 comprobaciones. Y lo que debería hacer el programa es borrar el segundo input cada vez que hago enter y mostrar el fondo en verde si es correcto o rojo si es incorrecto.

El problema lo tengo a la hora de borrar el campo del segundo input porque siempre me muestra rojo.

No se si es un problema de como estoy intentando restablecer el valor del segundo input, o es que debería hacerlo de otra manera. Os agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Adjunto código.

```js
function comparar() {
  $("#2").on('keydown', function(e) {
    let first = document.getElementById('1').value;
    let second = document.getElementById('2').value;
    let correcto;
    var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keycode == 13) {
      //document.getElementById('2').value = '';
      console.log(second)
      if (first == 4 && second == 4) {
        document.getElementById('menu_body').style.background = 'lightgreen';
        document.getElementById('correcto').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('incorrecto').style.display = "none";
      } else {
        document.getElementById('menu_body').style.background = 'red';
        document.getElementById('correcto').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('incorrecto').style.display = "block ";
      }
      document.getElementById('2').value = '';
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
  <h2>Lectura Etiquetas DMC</h2>
  <form action="#">
    <input id="1" maxlength="3" placeholder="Orden de producción" type="text" />
    <input id="2" type="text" maxlength="9" size="30" onkeydown="comparar()" placeholder="Lectura Pieza DMC" />
    <!--<input id="3" type="text" placeholder="Lectura Referencia AC" onkeyup="comparar()"/>--><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="correcto" style="text-align: center; font-size: 35px; display: none; margin-bottom: 50px">
  <br>
  <h1>LECTURA CORRECTA! </h1>
</div>
<div id="incorrecto" style="text-align: center; font-size: 35px; display: none; margin-bottom: 50px">
  <br>
  <h1>LECTURA INCORRECTA! </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Ya que tu código es HTML + JS, podés [edit] tu pregunta y agregar un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`) para poder reproducir tu problema en la pregunta misma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque esto esté dentro de la función `comparar()`:

```javascript
$("#2").on('keydown', function (e) {
```

segun parece a **jquery** le da igual, y siempre está a la escucha, por lo tanto yo haria dos cosas para solucionarlo.

1. Quitar la linea de definición de función `comparar()`. Es decir, borrar esta línea:

```javascript
function comparar(){
```

y su cierre `}` al final del javascript tambien.

2. Borrar la llamada a dicha función en el id 2. Es decir, cambiar esto:

```html
<input id="2" type="text" maxlength="9" size="30" onkeydown="comparar()" placeholder="Lectura Pieza DMC"/>
```

por esto

```html
<input id="2" type="text" maxlength="9" size="30" placeholder="Lectura Pieza DMC"/>
```

pues **siempre** está a la escucha gracias al **jquery** comentado al principio.

3. Luego, si lo que quieres es comparar ambos valores, debes cambiar esto:

```javascript
if (first == 4 && second == 4 ) {
```

por esto:

```javascript
if (first == second) {
```

Si quieres hacerlo en vanilla javascript (puro) quita la linea de jquery y agrega estas dos:

```javascript
campo2 = document.getElementById('2');
campo2.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
//$("#2").on('keydown', function(e) {
```

Y te quedará una cosa así (ejecuta el snippet siguiente):

```js
campo2 = document.getElementById('2');
campo2.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
//$("#2").on('keydown', function(e) {
  let first = document.getElementById('1').value;
  let second = document.getElementById('2').value;
  let correcto;
  var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keycode == 13) {
    if (first == second) {
      document.getElementById('menu_body').style.background = 'lightgreen';
      document.getElementById('correcto').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('incorrecto').style.display = "none";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('menu_body').style.background = 'red';
      document.getElementById('correcto').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('incorrecto').style.display = "block ";
    }
    document.getElementById('2').value = '';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu_body">
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <h2>Lectura Etiquetas DMC</h2>
    <form action="#">
      <input id="1" maxlength="3" placeholder="Orden de producción" type="text" />
      <input id="2" type="text" maxlength="9" size="30" onkeydown="" placeholder="Lectura Pieza DMC" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="correcto" style="text-align: center; font-size: 35px; display: none; margin-bottom: 50px">
    <br>
    <h1>LECTURA CORRECTA! </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="incorrecto" style="text-align: center; font-size: 35px; display: none; margin-bottom: 50px">
    <br>
    <h1>LECTURA INCORRECTA! </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esta es una opción que ya habia probado y de hecho no entiendo porque en mi web no esta funcionando, es como si no me detectara el evento si quito la funcion comparar. He copiado y pegado tu codigo por si era error mio. Pero no me sale ni un solo error en consola, no se ejecuta el codigo.

Comment: Se supone que usas jquery tambien... que version usas tu?  ¿Has copiado tanto el html como el js?  Copia ambos, deberia funcionar.

Comment: La web en la que estoy trabajando creo que es la 1.10.2, es antigua. Utilizo jquery, porque no encontre como hacer esa funcion en javascript puro. Probablemente sea ese el problema, sabrias hacer esa funcion con javascript?

Comment: Por cierto, solo funciona cuando le das a la tecla ENTER en el segundo campo, tal como lo tenias diseñado... ¿eso lo tienes en cuenta?

Comment: Si, lo tengo en cuenta, lo has hecho tal y como comento en mi problema. Deberia ejecutarse cuando pulsas enter en el segundo para poder comprobar varias veces.

Comment: Pues no se, yo probaria cambiando la version jquery por la que ves en el snippet por si acaso y para descartar ese problema.  Para hacerlo con javascript puro debes usar addEventListener

Comment: He añadido la linea de script que has puesto en el snippet cuando he copiado el codigo y nada. Te importaria modificar tu respuesta con la funcion hecha con javascript te lo agradeceria un montón.

Comment: Bueno, aparte de agregar esa linea tenias que quitar la que ya tenias de la antigua version de jquery para evitar solapamientos entre ellos, por si acaso.

Comment: Te acabo de modificar la respuesta y lo he puesto con vanilla javascript tambien. Mira a ver si ahora te funciona.

Comment: Lo siento, pero sigue sin funcionar. Dudando si el problema lo tenia en mi web. He creado un archivo html en mi escritorio. Y he vuelto a copiar tu codigo y probar ejecutarlo. Y me ocurre el mismo problema. He puesto un console.log para comprobar si entra en la funcion, y no me saca ningun log.

Comment: ¿Y cuando lo ejecutas aqui te funciona?  En el snippet me refiero... a ver si va a ser tu navegador... Aqui es donde lo he desarrollado:  https://jsfiddle.net/yjLq8n1e/  (mira a ver si alli te funciona, dale al boton RUN)

Comment: Si, cuando lo ejecuto tanto en el snippet como en el link que me has adjuntado funciona perfectamente. Pero dudo que sea por mi navegador, porque he probado tanto en firefox como google chrome, ambos actualizados.

Comment: Pues no se como lo haces tu en tu html, ya poco más puedo decirte, supongo que encierras el codigo javascript entre `<script></script>` cuando lo pones en el html o lo invocas mediante `<script src="elcodigo.js"></script>` por ejemplo.

Comment: Por si acaso lo he puesto todo en la parte del html para que lo veas aqui:  https://jsfiddle.net/yjLq8n1e/1/  y sigue funcionando bien... si copias eso en un html tal cual de tu web deberia funcionar

Comment: No se que es lo que estaba fallando, tendria algun error de codigo pero no me lo mostraba por consola, pero gracias por tu paciencia y por tu solucion te lo agradezco muchisimo!

Comment: Bueno, al fin, jolin, me has hecho sudar :-)  Venga, me alegro por ti, saludos!